# CSS Footer Separation

Tags: html, css, position, margin, footer

I have a fixed footer on my page, which consists of text and has no background image. I also have a fixed background image which is positioned to the bottom right. I was wandering what I could do to prevent my content from overlapping with both the footer and the background image as I scroll down the page. Is there anyway to put padding between them while I scroll?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a padding-bottom the height of your footer to your main container. Something like this:

```
.footer { height: 150px; }
.container { padding-bottom: 150px; }
```

This will prevent content to be under the fixed footer.

Edit: here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2KZyv/
When you reach the bottom of the page, the footer isn't on top of the content thanks to the bottom padding on the container.

Comment: That didn't work, the content is still visible under the footer as I scroll. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a white background on the footer, cause having a transparent fixed footer is bound to give overlapping problems. As for the background image on the bottom right, just include a `z-index` code and push it all the way back and you'll have everything on the top.